# Glimpse works only for 200 status code response (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, logging, error-handling, glimpse

I'm trying to enable a Glimpse icon on all the error pages to see what happened behind the scenes where debugging and tracing is most important, and I cannot make Glimpse work.

What I've tried:

```
<glimpse defaultRuntimePolicy="On" endpointBaseUri="~/Glimpse.axd">
    <runtimePolicies>
      <statusCodes>
        <add statusCode="500"/>
        <add statusCode="404"/>
      </statusCodes>
    </runtimePolicies>
</glimpse>
```

Does not help - no Glimpse icon in the corner of error pages. On "200 OK" pages Glimpse works fine.

I'm wondering if I'm the only one who thinks that tracing of request handling in case of exception is A MUST and #1 scenario that tools like Glimpse should cover?

Comment: Do you want the user/client to see the icon in their browsers?

Comment: Yes. I want to see Glimpse Icon on error pages as always as I see it on success 200-code pages. I would say seeing it on error page is more important then seeing it on success pages. I actually think it's obvious.

Comment: Are you using custom error pages or regular .Net yellow page messages? Are you running in Integrated pipeline mode?

Comment: I use standard .NET error yellow page, that was a while ago, it probably was integrated mode

Comment: I recently tried this and could not get glimpse to show up on YSOD error pages.